Parse HashiCorp vault secrets to Helm values.yaml file
I have a use case where OOB "out-of-the-box" Helm charts are being deployed on a k8s cluster.
In the example I'll share here, it will be a postgres Helm chart.
The issue I'm currently facing is that the helm chart and many other OOB helm charts don't cater for using an existing k8s secret to get secret values.
i.e.
making use of param: existingSecret for example.
The helm chart in this example get's secrets from the values.yaml file and parses them in and creates a configMap.
The are also a bunch of OOB helm charts that do something similar and maybe not pass the secret data to a configMap, but the chart itself creates a k8s secret (for example), also reading in values from the values.yaml file.
The example helm chart (postgres)
folder/file structure:
my-test-postgres-vaules.yaml
postgres
├── charts
├── Chart.yaml
├── templates
│   ├── config.yaml
│   ├── deployment.yaml
│   ├── pvc.yaml
│   └── service.yaml
└── values.yaml

See contents below of the files:
postgres/chart.yaml:
---
apiVersion: v2
name: postgres
description: A Helm chart for PostgreSQL database
type: application
version: 0.0.1
appVersion: 0.0.1
keywords:
  - database
  - postgres

postgres/templates/config.yaml:
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.postgres.config.name }}
  labels:
    group: {{ .Values.postgres.group }}
data:
{{- range .Values.postgres.config.data }}
  {{ .key }}: {{ .value }}
{{- end}}

postgres/templates/deployment.yaml:
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.postgres.name }}
  labels:
    app: {{ .Values.postgres.name }}
    group: {{ .Values.postgres.group }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .Values.postgres.name }}
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        {{- range $key, $value := .Values.podAnnotations }}
        {{ $key }}: {{ $value | quote }}
        {{- end }}
      labels:
        app: {{ .Values.postgres.name }}
        group: {{ .Values.postgres.group }}
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: {{ .Values.postgres.volume.name }}
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: {{ .Values.postgres.volume.pvc.name }}
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Values.postgres.name }}
          image: {{ .Values.postgres.container.image }}  
          ports:
            - containerPort: {{ .Values.postgres.container.port }}
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: {{ .Values.postgres.config.name }}
          volumeMounts:             
            - name: {{ .Values.postgres.volume.name }}
              mountPath: {{ .Values.postgres.volume.mountPath }} 

postgres/templates/pvc.yaml:
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: {{ .Values.postgres.volume.kind }}
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.postgres.volume.pvc.name }}
spec:
  accessModes:
    - {{ .Values.postgres.volume.pvc.accessMode }}
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: {{ .Values.postgres.volume.pvc.storage }}

postgres/templates/service.yaml:
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.postgres.name }}
  labels:
    group: {{ .Values.postgres.group }}
spec:
  type: {{ .Values.postgres.service.type }}
  selector:
    app: {{ .Values.postgres.name }}
  ports:
    - port: {{ .Values.postgres.service.port }}
      targetPort: {{ .Values.postgres.container.port }}

postgres/values.yaml:
---
replicaCount: 1

podAnnotations: {}

postgres:
  name: postgres
  group: db
  container:
    image: postgres:9.6-alpine
    port: 5432
  service:
    type: ClusterIP
    port: 5432
  volume:
    name: postgres-storage
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
    pvc:
      name: postgres-persistent-volume-claim
      accessMode: ReadWriteOnce
      storage: 4Gi
  config:
    name: postgres-config
    data:
       - key: key
         value: value

my-test-postgres-vaules.yaml:
---
podAnnotations:
  vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject: 'true'
  vault.hashicorp.com/role: 'test-db'
  vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-db-config.txt: 'kv-v2/data/database/config'

postgres:
  config:
    data:
      - key: POSTGRES_DB
        value: my-test-db
      - key: POSTGRES_USER
        value: my-test-user
      - key: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
        value: my-test-password

You will note that the chart DOES cater for podAnnotations.
Where I am leveraging HashiCorps Vault Agent Injector service by means of using a "side car" to inject my secrets stored in vault to the postgres pod, into a file called: /vault/secrets/db-config.txt that resides locally on the postgres container.
I followed instructions here to install vault, the vault agent injector as well as set the secrets on my vault server.
I install the postgres helm chart with:
helm install -f my-test-postgres-vaules.yaml postgres ./postgres
which returns successful:
NAME: postgres
LAST DEPLOYED: Wed Jun  5 19:57:42 2024
NAMESPACE: default
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 1
TEST SUITE: None

$ kubectl get deployments
NAME                   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
postgres               1/1     1            1           30s
vault-agent-injector   1/1     1            1           3h56m

kubectl get pods
NAME                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
postgres-f7f59555f-5b9sp                2/2     Running   0          63s
vault-0                                 1/1     Running   0          3h57m
vault-agent-injector-6d57d65964-9qzjx   1/1     Running   0          3h57m

If you look at the posgres pod, you will see it has two containers, one being postgres itself, and the other the vault-agent injector.
$ kubectl get pods $(kubectl get pod -l app=postgres -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}") -o jsonpath='{.spec.containers[*].name}'
postgres vault-agent

The postgres pod has also successfully got the secrets from vault, see below:
kubectl exec $(kubectl get pod -l app=postgres -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}") --container postgres -- cat /vault/secrets/db-config.txt
data: map[db-name:my-test-db password:my-test-password username:my-test-user]
metadata: map[created_time:2024-06-05T16:30:44.961447686Z custom_metadata:<nil> deletion_time: destroyed:false version:2]

I know that this does not solve my issue, but perhaps I can use something similar to parse in those secret values into the values.yaml file that many of these types of OOB charts needs?
I know it's possible to amend the helm chart itself, such that it doesn't create a configMap, or a k8s secret of its own, or even better, update the chart to use the param existingSecret, and then use vault secrets operator and create a VaultStaticSecrets CRD with my secrets.
The problem is that there are many OOB charts like this, and unpacking them, updating them, maintaining them, etc. just becomes a nightmare.
Whereas being able to inject vault secrets straight into the helm values.yaml file will be super beneficial for us and the vendors supplying these OOB charts that don't cater for using existing secrets with param: existingSecret for example.
Something like:
my-test-postgres-vaules.yaml:
---
postgres:
  config:
    data:
      - key: POSTGRES_DB
        value: <my vault secret here>.db-name
      - key: POSTGRES_USER
        value: <my vault secret here>.username
      - key: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
        value: <my vault secret here>.password

Thanks in advance for taking the time to review / answer my question :-)

Do you have kubernetes-auth configured? For the agent-injector to work, this needs to be set up.
